# Como saber em JAVA que o resultado do ResultSet está vazio?

Tags: java

Estou pesquisando no banco de dados, e tenho problema ao `SQL` retornar um valor vazio. Na verdade é possível que isto aconteça e por isto preciso manter preparado para tal. Qual método de identificar que não foi encontrado nenhum registro com aquele parâmetro ?

Ja tentei utilizar o `TRY/CATCH` porém não funcionou.

Meu código está assim:

```
 ResultSet rs_tbl_PESSOAS = con.query("SELECT * FROM tbl_PESSOAS WHERE XXXX= '" + w_obj.getString("XXXX") + "' and COD_IDENT_PESSO = '" + w_obj.getString("COD_IDENT_PESSO") + "';");
                    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs_tbl_PESSOAS.getMetaData();
                    int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
```

Comment: O que voce quer é checar se a query não retornou resultados para o resultset correto?

Comment: Quero chegar se ha dados retornados nesta query. Se la no banco retornou alguma linha na SQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar **next** . Normalmente se usa :

```
white(resultSet.next()){
   //Percorrer o resultado da sql
}
```

O que acontece é que se não houver resultados o primeiro **next** vai retornar falso. E você pode aproveitar fazendo o seguinte:

```
if(resultSet.next()){
   //Se passar ele vai estar na posicao 1 , já pronto para usar os getters
   do{
      //codigo
   }while(resultSet.next());
}else{
   //Se nao passar significa que não houve resultados
}
```

Você também pode usar o **ResultSetMetaData** . Ele tem todos os dados do result set.Mas seria melhor já saber se houve algum resultado.
Dá para pegar muitos mais dados com isso, quantas colunas, qual tipo, o nome da tabela e muito mais, dê uma olhada no [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html)(talves você ja conheça , porém)

Comment: O problema se usar o next, ele irá passar pro próxima linha da pilha caso exista algum retorno positivo.

Comment: O resultset começa em uma posição inutilizável, o primeiro next move para a primeira posição, não se esqueça disso! Mas mesmo assim, nesse caso você poderia usar o DO WHILE depois do if. Assim você não saltaria o primeiro.

Answer (score 5):

Um outra opção é utilizar o método [isBeforeFirst()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isBeforeFirst%28%29) também da classe `ResultSet`.

Este método retornará `true` se o cursor estiver antes do primeiro registro e `false` se o cursor estiver em qualquer posição ou se não há registros.

Portanto, se este método for chamado logo após fazer a *query* e ele retornar `false`, então é o indicativo que não foram retornados registros para a *query* realizada.

Exemplo:

```
if (!resultSet.isBeforeFirst()) 
   System.out.println("Não há registros.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Após o `while(){}`

Experimente por uma checagem se o `resultSet` percorreu até o último, ou seja, se achou registros ou não:

`if(!resultSet.isAfterLast()){}`

Caso o resultSet não contenha nenhuma linha a condição acima será verdadeira, servindo como um "else" para o while acima.