# Como validar quando o ResultSet não encontra nenhum valor?

Tags: java, sql

Estou tentado montar uma função Java `pesquisarCliente` onde a mesma deve consultar no Banco de Dados se existe ou não. Caso exista mais de um resultado deve retornar todos os registros, caso não encontre nada deve retornar para o usuário um aviso.

Utilizando o `while` ele me traz todos os registros conforme a pesquisa, porém não consegui validar quando ele não encontra nada. Se eu usar só o `if` ele funciona, valida se o registro existe ou não, porém apresenta um único registro. Tentei fazer a combinação do `while` e do `if`, sem sucesso.

```
public String pesquisarCliente(String pesquisarCliente) {

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {


        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER).newInstance();

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Nome Cliente: ");
        pesquisarCliente = ler.nextLine();

        String sql = "SELECT cpf_cnpj,nome_rs,ativo FROM tb_cliente WHERE (cpf_cnpj ='" + pesquisarCliente + "' AND ativo = 1) OR (nome_rs LIKE '%" + pesquisarCliente + "%' AND ativo = 1)";

        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        if(result.next()){ // Dúvida <===

        while (result.next()) {

            String cpfclient = result.getString("cpf_cnpj");
            int status = result.getInt("ativo");
            String nomeclient = result.getString("nome_rs");


            // Display valores
            System.out.print("CPF/CNPJ: " + cpfclient);
            System.out.print("\t Nome: " + nomeclient);

            System.out.println("\n=====================\n");

            PreparedStatement upgradeTempGeralCliente = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE tb_temp_geral SET [cpf_cnpj_Cliente] = '"+cpfclient+"', [nome_client]= '"+nomeclient+"' WHERE [id] = 1;");
    upgradeTempGeralCliente.executeUpdate();

            this.setNomeCliente(nomeclient);
            this.setCpfCliente(cpfclient);


        }
        }else{

            System.out.println("NÃO achei o cliente!");
        }

        result.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
        //ler.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {



    }

    return null;

}
```

Percebi que na linha `if(result.next()){ // Dúvida <===` se eu substituir `result.next()` por qualquer coisa que seja verdadeiro (por exemplo, `if(funciona == true)`) ele entra no `while` normalmente.

Penso eu que o erro está em utilizar o `result.next()` dentro do `if`. Mas como obter o retorno da pesquisa para retornar a mensagem "NÃO achei o cliente!"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado à todos!

Deu certo utilizando a resposta do @[Rodrigo Santiago](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/31231/rodrigo-santiago) em uma outra pergunta.

```
if (resultSet.next()) {
            //Se passar ele vai estar na posicao 1 , já pronto para usar os getters
            do {
                //codigo
            } while (resultSet.next());

 } else {
            //Se nao passar significa que não houve resultados
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Minha resposta vai ser bem parecida com o que respondi [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/396446/problemas-com-a-conex%C3%A3o-jdbc/396468#396468).

O método `rs.next()` irá andar no `ResultSet`, e caso exista um registro irá retornar `true`.

Lembrando que o `if( rs.next() )` irá só verificar se existe uma próxima linha como resultado, se você deseja iterar sobre várias linhas deve-se utilizar o `while( rs.next() )`.

Nesse caso, ambos surtem o mesmo efeito, a diferença é que utilizando `if( rs.next() )` e o `while( rs.next() )` em sequência acarretará na perda do primeiro registro retornado, visto que você já andou uma posição utilizando o `rs.next()`

Answer (score 1):

Bom, nos meus projetos, caso eu necessite muito saber se esse resultset está vazio ou não, eu faço o seguinte:

```java
rs.first(); //tenta mover o ponteiro ate a primeira linha caso exista
if (!rs.first()){ //se nao existir uma primeira linha então o resultSet esta nulo.
    return null;
}
```

Logo em seguida, para voltar o `resultSet` para o inicio (no caso para usar um `while(rs.next())`), você pode usar o comando:

```java
rs.beforeFirst();
```

Isso retorna o `resultSet` para a linha "Anterior a primeira"... Ou seja, quando executar o `while(rs.next())` ele vai ir automaticamente para a primeira linha (que no caso se chegou até aqui, é porque existe ao menos uma linha)...

Answer (score 1):

Conforme respondido por @cantoni [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110981/como-saber-em-java-que-o-resultado-do-resultset-est%C3%A1-vazio).

Um outra opção é utilizar o método [isBeforeFirst()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isBeforeFirst%28%29) também da classe `ResultSet`.

Este método retornará `true` se o cursor estiver antes do primeiro registro e `false` se o cursor estiver em qualquer posição ou se não há registros.

Portanto, se este método for chamado logo após fazer a query e ele retornar `false`, então é o indicativo que não foram retornados registros para a query realizada.

Exemplo:

```
if (!resultSet.isBeforeFirst()) System.out.println("Não há registros.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Não conheço `result.next()` mas pelo contexto eu diria que ao você usar no `if` e no `while` você está na verdade buscando o próximo resultado 2 vezes que acredito não ser o que queira.

Você pode dizer `var resultado = result.next()` e depois fazer `if (result != null)` ou `if (result.Count > 0)` a depender do que o `result.next()` retorne para ver se retornou algum resultado. Se não você retorna a mensagem que não achou o cliente.

Aí dentro do While você faz `while (resultado != null)` e no final dele (ainda dentro do `while`) faz `resultado = result.next()` de novo. Assim, na próxima iteração do `while` você já está verificando o próximo valor.